How can I use the Data Manager/API Playground UI in AWS Amplify Gen2 for my Sandbox environment?
When using AWS Amplify Gen2 is it somehow possible to use the Data Manager UI in the AWS Console for Sandbox Envs? Or is this just possible for 'real' deployments?
I am able to use it for my 'main' deployment, but I would llike to use it for my sandbox deployment as well for faster development cycles.

I am having the same issue.  I found this, brace yourself, it is not supported
https://repost.aws/questions/QU_f3P9W5KQ7KKc4xVaiHqLQ/how-can-i-use-the-data-manager-api-playground-ui-in-aws-amplify-gen2-for-my-sandbox-environment
The passage of interest is "Unfortunately, the Data Manager UI in the AWS Amplify Console is not available for sandbox environments in AWS Amplify Gen 2. The Data Manager and API Playground features are designed for use with deployed environments, typically associated with Git branches in your repository.Unfortunately, the Data Manager UI in the AWS Amplify Console is not available for sandbox environments in AWS Amplify Gen 2. The Data Manager and API Playground features are designed for use with deployed environments, typically associated with Git branches in your repository."
It does fly in the face of do whatever you want and we do the hard stuff. Amazon have chosen sandbox deploy speed over functionality.  I would love to see a local sandbox manager.  It would not that could look at local sandboxes and cloud deployments.
Going to add this reply to the other thread

Sandbox environments are similarly deployed to the other environments, so they have all the individual services deployed, just like previews and production environments.
You can go to the AWS AppSync portal and find your Sandbox's API, you can identify it by the ID (you can check your amplify_outputs.json file), then there you can access the "Queries", which is essentially an API playground, there you can run queries and mutations.
